# Finding rotate matrix which solves equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, matrix-equations

I try to solve the following problem: given a unit vector v, find rotate matrix R such that R*v = (0,0,..0,1) (vector that it's (n-1) components are 0 and the n'th component is 1).
I know that if I hadn't had the request that R is a rotate matrix it would have been simply system of linear equations. Any thoughts of how can I find such a rotate matrix?

Thanks

Comment: you will need to find a basis for the space that is orthogonal to the plane spanned by $v$ and $(0,0,\cdots, 1).$ once you have that you can find a block matrix $\pmatrix{\cos t&\sin t& 0\\-\sin t & \cos t & 0\\0&0&B}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Gram-Schmidt process, slightly modified. Start with the $n + 1$ vectors 
$$
v, e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n
$$
(where $e_i$ denotes the standard basis vector: 0s in all entries, but 1 in the $i$th entry) and call them $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{n+1}$.

Apply Gram-Schmidt to get
\begin{align}
w_1 &= v_1\\
u_1 &= w_1 / \|w_1 \|,
\end{align}

as a first step. $u_1$ (which is just $v$, of course) will be the first column of your matrix.

Now apply GS to $v_2$:
\begin{align}
w_2 &= v_2 - (v_2 \cdot u_1) u_1 \\
u_2 &= w^2 / \| w_2 \|
\end{align}
and then to $v_3$:
\begin{align}
w_3 &= v_3 - (v_3 \cdot u_1) u_1 - (v_3 \cdot u_2) u_2 \\
u_3 &= w^3 / \| w_3 \|
\end{align}
and so on.

If, in the course of doing this, you ever find $w_i = 0$, then throw $v_i$ out of your list and start work with the next item as $v_i$.

In general, this "$w_i = 0$" case happens right at the end: the $n+1$st vector is a linear combination of the previous $n$. But if it happens in the middle, you can just toss out that vector early.

When you're done, the vectors $u_i$ will form the rows of an orthogonal matrix. The vector $v$ is the first row, but reading your question carefully, I see it should be the last: so swap the first and last rows. Now the only question is whether the resulting matrix is a rotation. If the determinant is $+1$, it's a rotation; if not, then negate the first row and it will be.

(A natural question is "if you want $v$ in the last row, why not put it at the end of your list of vectors instead of the start?" Answer: I want $v$ unchanged, and in the GS process, only the first vector survives untouched, and it only does so if it's a unit vector.)

Comment: if v is one of R rows, doesn't it mean that Rv = (0..0) ? and what e1,..en should I take? simply a basis?

Comment: 1. I screwed up and said that the $u_i$ should be the columns of $R$; I should have said "rows"; I've edited to fix that. 2. $v$ should actually be the *last* row ...  so just before the "fix the determinant" step, please swap the first and last rows (I'll edit that as well). 3. If each of the $u_i$ ($i = 2, 3, \ldots$) is perpendicular to  $v$, then a row that contains $u_i$, when multiplied by the column vector $v$, will give $0$. On the other hand, the last row will be $v$, and that row, multiplied by the column vector $v$, will give $v \cdot v = 1$.

Comment: Also: the vectors $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors; I've edited to add that as well.